# Loading a DataGridView Binded to a Dictionary in Separate Window XAML WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, xaml, user-interface

I am currently trying to load a separate window that comes up when a user clicks a certain location on a map. I want the window to display Business object data that is held within a Dictionary in C#.

For some reason, I can't get the window to display anything, it just stays blank.

I am defining all of the columns/rows in my own code and filling the data table, and not in the designer.

Here is my code for some clues:

XAML:
BusinessDataWindow.xaml

```
   <Window x:Class="BusinessLocator.BusinessDataTable"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DigoohBusinessLocator"

    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Title="BusinessDataTable" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>

    <DataGrid x:Name="BusinessDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source = BusinessDataGridView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="412" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="785">

    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

---

And here is the code behind the XAML (Please excuse some commented lines):
BusinessDataWindow.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>

/// Interaction logic for BusinessDataTable.xaml

/// </summary>

public partial class BusinessDataWindow : Window

{

    //System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid BusinessDataGrid;

    //DataGridView BusinessDataGridView;

    DataTable BusinessDataTable;

    Dictionary<string, Business> BusinessLocationDictionary;

    public BusinessDataWindow(Dictionary<string, Business> BusinessLocationDictionary)

    {

        //this.BusinessDataGrid = null;

        this.BusinessLocationDictionary = BusinessLocationDictionary;



        this.initializeDataGridView();

        //this.InitializeComponent();

        //this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataGrid_Loaded);

    }



    public DataGridView BusinessDataGridView

    {

        get;

        set;

    }



    private void initializeDataGridView()

    {

        this.BusinessDataGridView = new DataGridView();

        this.BusinessDataTable = new DataTable();

        int businessCount = this.BusinessLocationDictionary.Values.Count;



        string nameColumn = "Name";

        string placeIdColumn = "Place ID";

        string addressColumn = "Address";

        string phoneNumberColumn = "Phone Number";

        string OwnerColumn = "Owner";



        // Add the columns to the DataGridView.

        this.BusinessDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(nameColumn, typeof(string)));

        this.BusinessDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(placeIdColumn, typeof(string)));

        this.BusinessDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(addressColumn, typeof(string)));

        this.BusinessDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(phoneNumberColumn, typeof(string)));

        this.BusinessDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(OwnerColumn, typeof(string)));

       

        List<Business> BusinessList = this.BusinessLocationDictionary.Values.ToList<Business>();



        // Add the rows to the DataGridView.

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < businessCount; rowIndex++)

        {

            this.BusinessDataTable.Rows.Add(BusinessList.ElementAt(rowIndex));

            this.populateDataGridCells();

        }

    }



    private void populateDataGridCells()

    {

        int businessCount = this.BusinessLocationDictionary.Values.Count;

        List<Business> BusinessList = this.BusinessLocationDictionary.Values.ToList<Business>();



        // Populate the rows to the DataGridView.

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < businessCount; rowIndex++)

        {

            DataGridViewRow row = this.BusinessDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex];



            row.Cells[rowIndex].Value = BusinessList.ElementAt(rowIndex);

        }



        this.BusinessDataGridView.DataSource = this.BusinessDataTable;

    }
```

}

Comment: Hoping you havent commented InitializeComponent() :D

Comment: Do I have to implement that method myself for something to display?

Comment: Also at line: DataGridViewRow row = this.BusinessDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex]; I receive a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Index was out of range.

Comment: When you add > window the stub has initializecomponent in the ctor. That line turns creates your ui.  If you want any view, it's rather important to have that in your constructor.

Comment: You're using rowindex to index both x and y. Rows and columns. That seems unlikely to be right. I don't follow what you're trying to do. You have a datatable and a dictionary which seem disconnected. I don't see why you have both.  To bind a datatable you should bind it's default view to itemssource of a datagrid. Datagrid in wpf.

Answer (score 0):

You commented out *this.InitializeComponent();* in your constructor. Without calling this method no controls will be generated.

So it should look like this:

```
public BusinessDataWindow(Dictionary<string, Business> BusinessLocationDictionary)
{
            //this.BusinessDataGrid = null;
            this.BusinessLocationDictionary = BusinessLocationDictionary;
            this.initializeDataGridView();
            this.InitializeComponent();
            //this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataGrid_Loaded);
}
```

As for your error in line *DataGridViewRow row = this.BusinessDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex];* it's because your BusinessDataGridView has no rows.